# Query a list of columns and tables from different databases in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have multiple databases and multiple tables in each one, how do I query a list that contains a column name, table name, and database name that matches with a key word in the column name?

Example: look for the database, table and column that has ID in the column name

```
WHERE column_name LIKE '%ID%'
```

Comment: If all the databases are in same Server, It can be easily obtained.

Answer (score 0):

`master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb` procedure executes the given command in all databases. Using that you can get columns of all databases. Question mark will be replace in every step with current database name. You can use ? everywhere in your command.

```
CREATE TABLE #Columns
(
    database_name sysname,
    table_name sysname,
    column_name sysname
);

EXEC master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb '
USE [?]
INSERT #Columns (database_name, table_name, column_name)
SELECT DB_NAME(), OBJECT_NAME(c.object_id), c.name 
FROM sys.columns AS c 
WHERE c.name LIKE ''%ID%'''

SELECT * FROM #Columns AS c
```